# Авторитет или репутация?

Tags: синонимы

Вопрос, кто прав: человек 1 или человек 2? В данном контексте какое слово является более уместным: репутация или авторитет? Я не отрицаю, что слово авторитет в какой-то степени близко к репутации, но по моему мнению его использование здесь не совсем корректно, а уж говорить, что авторитет и репутация являются синонимами это вообще какой-то бред. Это как назвать авторитетным человека, про которого говорят "у него хорошая репутация". Причем тут авторитет? Авторитет подразумевает некоторую "силу" и "власть", а тут разговор идет не о них.
Или я не прав?

> Человек 1: А реально ли фрилансить не раскрывая личные данные каждому встречному? Не в том смысле, что скрывать их от заказчиков, а просто не выкладывать в паблик?
>
> Человек 2: Без авторитета не выйдет. Да и вряд ли будут платить Пупкину. Ну разве только без предоплаты, на честном слове.
>
> Человек 1: Ты уверен, что хотел сказать то, что сказал?
>
> Человек 3: Эмм..
> Контакты вскрываются в момент общения с заказчиком. А до этого момента ты не Пупукин, а Веб-студия "Вектор".
> Авторитет с авторством ничего общего не имеет, тут ты какую-то чушь сказал.
>
> Человек 2: С чего ты взял, что я имел в виду авторство? Слово «авторитет» у меня ассоциируется с репутацией.
>
> Человек 1: Ты какой-то странный. Так бы и сказал, что репутация, причем тут авторитет?
>
> Человек 2: Вы откуда к нам пожаловали? 99% людей ассоциируют авторитет с репутацией
>
> Человек 1: То, что авторитет связан с репутацией не означает, что авторитет==репутация
>
> Человек 2: Авторитет = репутация. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/aphorism/4/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A2

Answer (score 1):

Авторитет и репутация - это не одно и тоже.

Авторитет -  общепризнанное значение, влияние;( Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).   Авторитет — это такое качество человека, когда его очень уважают окружающие люди за его дела, познания, жизненный опыт и т. д.

Иметь авторитет, пользоваться авторитетом у кого-либо, среди кого-либо. | Приобрести, укрепить, утратить, потерять, подорвать авторитет. | Огромный, большой авторитет.( Толковый словарь  Дмитриева).

Репутация - это сложившееся положительное, благоприятное общественное мнение о человеке или группе людей. Она не подразумевает никакого влияния, общепризнанного значения. 
Эти два слова не являются синонимами. В данном контексте, насколько я понял , речь идет именно о репутации, а не об авторитете.

Comment: Поддерживаю.Репутация-доброе имя,имидж,мнение, а авторитет - сила имени, вес в обществе, т.е. значение хорошей репутации, но есть плохая репутация - это уже не авторитет. Здесь скорее сочетаются "репутация" с "авторством"

Answer (score 0):

Авторитет и репутация - разные понятия, хотя и связанные друг с другом.

Репутация может быть у каждого человека - это сложившееся общественное мнение, в то же время репутация может быть хорошей или плохой.

Авторитет  есть далеко не у каждого: человек пользуется или не пользуется авторитетом в определенном обществе. Люди, имеющие авторитет, влияют на свое окружение, при этом они могут обладать или не обладать властью. Разумеется, люди с плохой репутацией авторитетом пользоваться не могут.

Об авторитете уместно говорить применительно к коллективу, когда общество имеет постоянный состав участников. В приведенном примере при общении с заказчиком речь идет, скорее, о репутации, так как заказчик не входит в такой коллектив, но интересуется мнением этого коллектива относительно конкретного лица.